# Moving between two points in canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-animation

I have 2 points(x1,y1) and (x2,y2). I need to move the image from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2). Please let me know if there is any methods in android SDK to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing a custom view that handles it's on onDraw method you could:

1. Create a [path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) object:
2. Move to position 1 using the moveTo method
3. line to position 2 using the line2 method
4. Create a [path measure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PathMeasure.html) object.
5. User the path measure object to animate to the position.([Here](http://c05mic.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/animating-a-bitmap-using-path-and-pathmeasure-android/) is an example of that--note you will have to do it a little differently as the code doesn't show View.onDraw & View.invalidate being called).

Alternatively if you aren't handling your own on draw, you might be able to simply use a [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you need is an animation.

Search this site for `Animation Drawable` and you'll get tons of examples :)